# Prove that if $n$ mod $4 = 3$, then $n$ must have a prime factor of the form $4k + 3$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

[Top half is my work and the bottom half is what the professor has given me to help guide me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBJKQ.jpg)

I need help solving the problem "Prove that if $n$ mod $4 = 3$ then $n$ must have a prime factor of the form $4k + 3$.  Our professor gave us a hint (We know that $n$ can't have any even factors, so all of its prime factors must be odd.  Can all of them be of the form $4k + 1$?)  The attached image is what I have so far...but my understanding of the material is pretty poor at best...this is my second time taking discrete math and I just can't seem to understand all the mathematical lingo that gets tossed around.  Even my prior college calculus course was a simple plug and chug style course...but discrete is just a different beast and I can't understand any of the concepts.  I've only been able to muddle through all the problems by constantly asking the professor for help or by googling my problem and trying to take pieces of whatever solutions I can find.  I've found similar problems to finding prime numbers with the form $4k + 1$, but they all have explanations that are entirely Greek to me and I can't pull anything from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1: $n$ is prime, in which case, you're done.

Case 2: $n$ is composite. It has no even factors so all prime factors are odd.

An odd prime factor is either of the form: $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ or $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

If *all* prime factors were of the first form, then their product would also give a residue of $1$ modulo $4$ (because $1^m = 1$). Hence at least one prime factor must have a residue of $3$ modulo $4$, and you're done.

Comment: I guess I'm confused because where does "p mod 4 = 1 mod 4" come from?  How am I supposed to know that an odd prime factor is always p mod 4 = 1 mod 4 or p mod 4 = 3 mod 4?

Comment: First of all, you don't have to write : "$p \mod 4 = 1 \mod 4$", simply $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ would do. Second, there are only $4$ possible remainders if a number is divided by $4$, namely $0,1,2,3$. If the remainder is either $0$ or $2$, the number is even (it would be in either of the forms $4k$ or $4k+2$, which are both divisible by $2$). So  odd prime factors can only have remainder $1$ or $3$, which is why what I asserted holds.

Comment: Okay, that I can understand...I'm not sure how I am supposed to know that without prior explanation, but I understand the answer now, thank you!

Comment: @user280455 No prob, glad to help! :)

Answer (score 3):

The product of
two number of the form
4k+1 is also of the form
4k+1.

Therefore,
a number of the form
4k+3
must have at least one factor
of the form 4k+3.

Also,
since the product of
two numbers of the form 4k+3
is of the form 4k+1,
a number of the form
4k+3
must have an odd number of factors
of the form 4k+3.